# Trouble making columns read-only in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Hi I'm having a bit trouble with locking my columns in my datagrid in silverlight.

```
void proxy_ListAllGroupsCompleted(object sender, gkws.ListAllGroupsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        grouplist = e.Result;

        List<allGroups> source = new List<allGroups>();


        for (int i = 0; i < grouplist[0].Count; i++)
        {
            source.Add(new allGroups()
            {

                ID = Convert.ToInt32(grouplist[0][i]),
                Name = grouplist[1][i],
                CreationDate = grouplist[2][i],
                Creator = grouplist[3][i]
            });
        }

        mainGroupDG.ItemsSource = source;

        mainGroupDG.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;
        mainGroupDG.Columns[2].IsReadOnly = true;
        mainGroupDG.Columns[3].IsReadOnly = true;
    }
```

When I debug I get the error "Index was out of range". Although my datagrid auto-generates the column before I try to lock them.

Thanks for the help.

Wardh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you're setting the IsReadOnly, the columns have yet to be created.
What you need to do is to catch an event from the DataGrid that happens AFTER the columns have been created. for example, you could do this:

```
    private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But Doesn't seem to work either. Still getting the same message. That the index is out of bounds.

Comment: On another note I tried to up vote you on your answer. But I don't have enough reputation. If you up me I can up you :)

Comment: you can't get MyGrid.Columns, but u can use e.Column as i showed